# warning: format not a string literal, argument types not checked

Tags: c, string, glib

I'm attempting to learn C and already I've run into an issue.
I assume its trivial but I need to know it. I have written:

```
char *seconds_to_string (guint seconds)
{
    long days, hours, minutes;
    char *time = NULL;
    const char *minutefmt;
    const char *hourfmt;
    const char *secondfmt;

    days    = seconds / (60 * 60 * 24);
    hours   = (seconds / (60 * 60));
    minutes = (seconds / 60) - ((days * 24 * 60) + (hours * 60));
    seconds = seconds % 60;

    minutefmt = ngettext ("%ld minute", "%ld minutes", minutes);
    hourfmt = ngettext ("%ld hour", "%ld hours", hours);
    secondfmt = ngettext ("%ld second", "%ld seconds", seconds);

    minutefmt = ngettext ("%ld minute", "%ld minutes", minutes);
    hourfmt = ngettext ("%ld hour", "%ld hours", hours);
    secondfmt = ngettext ("%ld second", "%ld seconds", seconds);

    char *fmt;
    /* Translators: the format is "X hours X minutes X seconds" */
    fmt = g_strdup_printf (_("%s %s %s"), hourfmt, minutefmt, secondfmt);
    time = g_strdup_printf (fmt, hours, minutes, seconds);
    g_free (fmt);

    ---------------------------------------------------------------------

    return time;
}
```

warning in line with:

```
time = g_strdup_printf (fmt, hours, minutes, seconds);
```

Can anyone help please?

UPDATE:

compile with

```
scan-build make CFLAGS='-Wformat-nonliteral'
```

Comment: Could you show us the prototype of `g_strdup_printf`? It sounds like your parameters aren't fitting the prototypes types.

Comment: You could avoid the warning by doing the operations in reverse order: first format the hours, minutes, and seconds values each into their own string, then format those strings together with `_("%s %s %s")`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's just a warning.

`g_strdup_printf()`, like `printf()`, uses the first parameter as the format specifier, if it's a string literal like `"%d Hours:%d Minutes"`, the compiler can check the parameters that follows, see if the type match. (in this example, if the two parameters are of type `int`)

But in your code, the format specifier is not a string literal, but a string that you generate manually, so the compiler can't check the type for you.

Comment: I understood this part by myself, but not how to avoid the error. Is there some way of silencing this warning per-instance, instead of globally disabling it, as would be the case if using compiler flags?

Answer (score 0):

Without you specifying what compiler you're using it's hard to know for sure, but to me it looks like the warning you're getting is benign. It looks like your compiler can normally do some checking on `printf` invocations based on the format string provided: for instance, if you say `printf("%d", arg1, arg2)` it might notice that your format string expects one argument but your `printf` call provides two.

But in your code, the format string isn't a literal, it's a value produced by some other function. The compiler isn't smart enough to figure out what that string ought to be, so it issues you a warning telling you that it's not going to give you the safety net you might be expecting.

It is safe to ignore or suppress this warning so long as you're sure that the call that generates the warning is actually correct.